# Does checks the internet connection in the apps, affects the application performance in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, networking

I want to check the net connection in my application. In my application i have eight buttons in the directory page. When i click the button, i have to check the net connection, if the net connection is available, then have to parsed the data and displayed in the table view. In my application, mostly i have done parsing and loads the web url's in the web view and used web services. Now i have completed my application, but overall application performance is little bit slow, So what i am thinking, i have checked each and every url functions be for the internet connections. I have also used reachability(from Apple Docs) code. So which code will be used in my applications for improving the performance of the apps.

Note:

In my client feed back, when compared to the performance of the application while runs in the WIFI, it much faster and runs in the 3G(Mobile Services) the performance will be little slow. So how can i improve my application performance, while checking the internet connection? Does any need to check the application runs in the WIFI or 3G?

I had used this code for checking the net connection in my apps,

```
NSStringEncoding enc;

NSError *error;

NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"] usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];

if (connected == nil) {

        NSString * infoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please check your connection and try again."];

        UIAlertView * infoAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Connection Error" message:infoString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [infoAlert show];

        [infoAlert release];


    } else {

        [self details:castString]; // Parsing method calls
  }
```

So how can i improve the application performance, while checks the internet connection? and does affects the application performance?

Comment: Before making any assumptions about the performance of your application, always profile it to see where your true bottlenecks lie.  Use the Time Profiler, Object Allocations, etc. instruments to pinpoint where the performance issues are located in your application.  You might be surprised at what you find.

Comment: @Brad Larson, Thanks for the reply.I will check it. May i know wats the difference between Build and Analyze and using instrument. Both are to find the memory leaks. What i am asking, Some times cleared all the leaks while using Build and Analyze, but using the instruments, it will show some leaks. Does Build and Analyze is enough to checking the Memory leaks? Always have some clarification on both, so please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Build and analyze can not be trusted 100%. This is because, being a static analyzer, it may not report correctly all of the leaks in your code. In many cases, it may also mistakenly report false positives. Therefore, you must use both the analyzer and Instruments to find and remove all of the leaks. Instruments will give you full details of what is happening at runtime, whilst the analyzer only reports problems that may be discovered at compile time, without actually running your application.

Comment: @Pugal - Instruments does a lot more than find memory leaks.  Performance issues within your application can come from a number of different sources, and Instruments lets you profile your application from multiple perspectives (most CPU-consuming methods, most allocations, leaks, display performance, etc.).  It's best to not just rely on one way of examining your application, because then you can miss things.  For example, heap shots can find memory accumulations that aren't technically leaks, but can still cause slowdowns and crashes.

Comment: @unforgiven - I don't know that I've yet had the Clang Static Analyzer return a false positive.  False negatives are common, particularly with instance variables, because it can only really parse what happens within the context of a single method or function.

Answer (score 0):

So, naturally internet connection checking (assuming you're correctly doing it) will typically take longer on 3G than WiFi. This isn't that newsworthy. So if your issue is:

"it takes longer to check for connectivity, download, and parse on 3G"

...well, there are no surprises there.

To be honest, if you're using Apple's reachability code 'out of the box' there could be a lot of things going on here. How are you making the reachability call? Because Apple's sample does everything synchronously, so if you're calling it on the main thread there's your problem.